# Adding multiple lines of different colors in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I am trying to plot multiple lines in a single figure, and I want each line to be of unique color, I came to know that matplotlib does that by default. But in my case it isn't working. I get same color for each of the lines in the figure.

```
from sklearn import datasets
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Loading the Boston dataset from the sklearn and creating a dataframe 
boston = datasets.load_boston()
data = pd.DataFrame(boston.data, columns = boston.feature_names)


#for dropping multiple column 
dataDrop = data.drop(['CRIM','DIS', 'ZN', 'INDUS','CHAS','NOX', 'RAD', 
'TAX','LSTAT', 'B', 'PTRATIO', 'RM'], axis=1)


#converting to numpy array
m = 20
dataArray = dataDrop['AGE'].values
absMean = dataArray.mean()

for k in range(0,10):
    n = len(dataDrop.index)
    p = random.random()
    c = int(n*p)
    #Uniform sampling of c elements from the above
    mean = 0 
    values = np.empty([1, 2])
    for i in range(0,m):
        mean = ( mean*i + np.random.choice(dataArray, c).mean() ) / (i+1)
        print mean, i
        tuple = np.array([mean, i])
        values = np.vstack([values,tuple])
    print values
    plt.plot(values[1:,1], values[1:,0])
plt.axhline(absMean, color = 'red')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Could you please post a fully working, minimal example. This should include the necessary imports `numpy` and `matplotlib.pyplot` and you should replace `dataArray` by some toy data as well as give valid definitions of `n` and `m`

Comment: @ml4294 I have updated the code. Have a look!

Comment: I think you have to explain much more in detail what you want to achieve. When I run the code from the question I get [this output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IfLHB.png), which does have different line colors.

Answer (score 1):

See https://matplotlib.org/users/colors.html. For example:

```
plt.plot(values[1:,1], values[1:,0], 'C1')
```

Comment: This method works, but I am looking for something generic. Using above I can only specify 10 colors. I want unique colors every time. And why isn't matplotlib plotting with different color every time in loop.